# How to check is subnet allocated with another resource in azure using Fluent API or management API?

Tags: azure-virtual-network, subnet, azure-application-gateway, azure-management-api, azure-fluent-api

I am creating Application gateway using ARM templete now I want to check after select the virtual network subnet should not be allocated any other resource if allocated then show the message like Subnet must have only have Application Gateway.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my understanding, you want to list all resources that are connected to the virtual network. If so, you can use the rest API `Get Virtual Networks`.

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/{virtualNetworkName}}?api-version=2020-07-01
```

If one subnet has been allocated any other resource, it will return these configurations in `subnet` property. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/virtualnetwork/virtualnetworks/get).

For example

[image]

Comment: Yes I agree with you and  I am already using this API  and  managing validation Angular Side but I want to manage this API side  so can you help how to Deserilize this in class of object . like Subnet is class and property like Name, Delegations, IpConfigurations and fetch the value from this result.