# Get Azure resources associated with a subnet through Azure Resource Graph Query

Tags: azure, subnet, azure-nsg, azure-resource-graph

I am looking to fetch all resources associated with a subnet. I could find references oh how to do it the other way around (fetch a particular resource and it includes the subnet it is associated with), but can't find any documents where we can fetch all resources linked with a subnet.

My ultimate goal is to fetch all azure resources which use a particular network security group. That led me to the above question.

From another question I understand I can use a REST Api to get details for a specific virtual network. [How to check is subnet allocated with another resource in azure using Fluent API or management API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66261092/how-to-check-is-subnet-allocated-with-another-resource-in-azure-using-fluent-api). I would appreciate if someone could suggest anyway to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself :p. You get the associated devices within the subnet details along with other details on getting virtualnetworks.

Resource graph query:

```
resources
| where type =~ "microsoft.network/virtualnetworks"
```

properties->subnets->properties->ipConfigurations

The ipConfigurations are the connected devices.

Comment: Hey, did you ever finish the query to fetch all resources that are attached to a particular NSG, if so I would love to take a look. Been trying to figure out the query but struggling.

Answer (score 1):

It is here under Virtual Network.

[image]