# Who is using the Subnet inside a VNet in Azure

Tags: azure, networking, subnet, vnet

I want to see my network topology including the subnets and each resource that uses each subnet such as App Service or Functions etc but I cannot find the options in the portal.

[image]

How can I see which resources are using a subnet?

Comment: Try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/view-network-topology

Comment: @PeterBons no, I see the topology there but I can see only the vnet and sub-net and no more like my App Services or Azure Functions

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71902414/get-azure-resources-associated-with-a-subnet-through-azure-resource-graph-query once check this

Answer (score 0):

The network topology for a particular vnet can be found in the **Overview**. This topology preview will include:

1. Vnet
2. Subnet
3. NIC
4. NSGs
5. Public IPs
6. VMs

**See the screenshot below for more clarity:**
[image]

Hope it will help :)